# retrieve permalinks of posts inside custom post type by using post ID

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have these custom post types registered as shown in the image below -

[image]

In each of these custom post types, there are many posts. I have the function to retrieve the post IDs of each posts inside but I don't have a function to retrieve the permalinks.

I've used Pods Framework to get this done. How can I retrieve the permalinks on each posts using the post ID?

The end result should be something like -

> echo home_url() / post_type / post_name

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
<?php echo post_permalink( $ID ); ?>
```

where ID is the id of the post.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_permalink